# Does Oracle's Entity Framework provider support DbGeography?

Tags: entity-framework-5, oracle-spatial

We are working on a project that uses EF5.0 to connect to an Oracle 11g R2 database. We are using Oracle's own EF provider.

Now we would like to convert EF 5.0's `DbGeography` types to **Oracle Spatial**. This is not supported by all EF providers.

**Is it supported by Oracle's own EF provider?**

I cannot find any documentation on it here: [Oracle EF Provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)

And when trying to find the answer on Google, I can only find websites related to Devart's dotConnect EF provider, or related to SQL Server.

P.S.: We are extending the code generation routines of the provider heavily, and we have found that Oracle's own EF provider is much much simpler to extend than the one of Devart, so that's the reason we're not switching to Devart. So please, don't answer with *'use Devart's dotConnect'*.

Comment: Could you please describe what you meant when you wrote "we have found that Oracle's own EF provider is much much simpler to extend than the one of Devart" in more details? We would like to understand your problem better.

Comment: We need to extend and rewrite the generation of MSL, SSDL and DDL (PL/SQL) to our needs. Some examples: We are generating code for stored procedures in the `SSDL --> DDL` process. Those stored procedures need to be imported and mapped in the `CSDL --> MSL` and `CSDL --> SSDL` processes. These things we have to do for SQL Server as well as for Oracle. With SQL Server, it works like a charm, the problem is Oracle. My predecessor said he tried it with both ODP.NET and Devart's dotConnect, but it only worked on ODP.NET. Was he wrong?

Comment: We don't see any reasons why this task cannot be solved with dotConnect for Oracle. 
If you decide to try dotConnect for Oracle once again in future and have any further questions, please contact us (support at devart*com), and we will help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently ODP.NET does not support EF spatials. Please take a look at these links:

- https://community.oracle.com/thread/2562821
- https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=18357:39:101895119491249::NO::P39_ID:27261